# Do not print the error when running the AWS commmand

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am trying to delete the security groups by running the command

```
for i in `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=vpc-id,Values="${vpcid}" | grep sg- | sed -E 's/^.*(igw-[a-z0-9]+).*$/\1/'`; do aws ec2 delete-security-group --group-id $i; done
```

It will delete the custom security group successfully. However, return an error when trying to delete a default security group. I don't want the error to be returned on the terminal, and instead just return nothing.

I have tried to add `|| true` at the end of `delete-security-group` command, which looks like

```
for i in `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=vpc-id,Values="${vpcid}" | grep sg- | sed -E 's/^.*(igw-[a-z0-9]+).*$/\1/'`; do aws ec2 delete-security-group --group-id $i || true; done
```

while the error is still printed on the terminal. Any helps

Answer (score -1):

using `command 2>/dev/null` to redirect the error